# How to call unmanaged dll to populate struct in C# using a pointer

Tags: c#, c, dll, marshalling, unmanaged

I'm trying to use C# to get data from a file using a function in an unmanaged 3rd party dll. The function takes a pointer to a struct as an input, and returns a status flag for the success of the operation (not used in the code below). The 3rd party vendor supplies the following code in C for how to call the dll function:

DllCaller.h

```c
#pragma pack(1)
struct Event
{
    int event_type;
    double time_stamp;
    char event_text[200];
};

typedef enum Status (*_GetEventList)(struct Event* event_list);

_GetEventList GetEventList;
```

DllCaller.c

```c
int event_list_cnt;
struct Event* event_list;

hInstLibrary = LoadLibrary(lib_name);

GetEventList = (_DWGetEventList)GetProcAddress(hInstLibrary, "GetEventList);

printf("\nEVENTS:\n");
event_list_cnt = 2;
event_list = malloc(sizeof(struct Event) * event_list_cnt);
GetEventList(event_list);
for(i = 0; i < event_list_cnt; i++)
{
    printf("EVENT: type = %i, text = %s, position = %fsec \n", 
        event_list[i].event_type, event_list[i].event_text, 
        event_list[i].time_stamp);
}
free(event_list);

FreeLibrary(hInstLibrary)
```

The output from running this on an example file is:

EVENTS:

EVENT: type = 1, text = storing started, position = 0.000000sec

EVENT: type = 2, text = storing stopped, position = 110,825682sec

In other words each field in the event_list struct is an array of length two.

In the above code I have simplified the vendor's example code and omitted some things that I deem irrelevant to the present issue.

This I how I have tried to implement the same functionality in C#:

```cs
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1, CharSet=CharSet.Ansi)]
public struct Event
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, ArraySubType = UnmanagedType.I4)]
    public int[] event_type;

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, ArraySubType = UnmanagedType.R8)]
    public double[] time_stamp;

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, ArraySubType = UnmanagedType.LPStr, SizeConst = 200)]
    public char[] event_text;
}

[UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
private delegate Status GetEventList(IntPtr ptrToEventList);

public Event GetEventList()
{
    // this.pDll is a pointer to the dll library.
    IntPtr pAddressOfFunctionToCall = NativeMethods.GetProcAddress(this.pDll, "GetEventList");
    GetEventList getEventList = (GetEventList)Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer(pAddressOfFunctionToCall, typeof(GetEventList));

    int eventListCount;
    this.GetEventListCount(out eventListCount, out errorMessage);

    int mem = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(Event));

    // The multiplication by two is because I already know that
    // the struct should be populated by two events.
    IntPtr structPtr = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(2 * mem);

    Event eventList;

    try
    {
        getEventList(structPtr);
        eventList = (Event)Marshal.PtrToStructure(structPtr , typeof(Event));
    }
    finally
    {
        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(structPtr);
    }

    return eventList;
}
```

If I run this on the same example file as the C code above the event_type and time_stamp vectors in eventList will have length 1, and the event_text will have length 200. The values in these fields will contain correct information for the first event - the one of event_type 1 - as printed out by the C code above. What should be populated in the eventList is of course vectors of length 2 containing the two events, but I have been unsuccessfull in modifying the code to do this. The above code is the only one I have managed to write that populates anything at all in the struct. I have tried to play around with specifying the event_text field as a string instead of a char, but that only results in AccessViolationException errors, probably because I have not implemented it correctly.

Can anyone help me fix the above code so that the eventList is populated correctly?

Thanks!

/Elfendahl

EDIT:
Updated C# code with Event structure corrected and attempt to allocate Event[] in C# before passing it to the unmanaged dll:

```cs
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1, CharSet=CharSet.Ansi)]
public struct Event
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)]
    public int event_type;

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.R8)]
    public double time_stamp;

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, ArraySubType = UnmanagedType.LPStr, SizeConst = 200)]
    public char[] event_text;
}

[UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
private delegate Status GetEventList(ref Event[] eventList);

public Event[] GetEventList()
{
    // this.pDll is a pointer to the dll library.
    IntPtr pAddressOfFunctionToCall = NativeMethods.GetProcAddress(this.pDll, "GetEventList");
    GetEventList getEventList = (GetEventList)Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer(pAddressOfFunctionToCall, typeof(GetEventList));

    Event[] eventList = new Event[2];
    getEventList(ref eventList);

    return eventList;
}
```

I don't know if the above code looks as poorly formatted on your screen as it does on mine (indents and blank new lines are omitted) but I have been unable to get to look any better.

Comment: Why did you make `event_type` and `time_stamp` arrays in C#?

Comment: Ha! Very good observation, leppie! This is because I'm sometimes very sloppy at reading code. My mind read the `event_list[i].event_type` as `event_list.event_type[i]` Ok, I modified the code so that `event_type` and `time_stap` no longer are arrays. Following this I also modified the code such that eventList is an Event[] and `eventList = (Event[])Marshal.PtrToStructure(structPtr , typeof(Event[]));` Running this code gives a "MissingMethodException: No parameterless constructor defined for this object". Any thoughts on how to fix that?

Comment: Perhaps `Marshal.PtrToStructure` does not deal with array types. Try doing them one by one.

Comment: BTW, from what I can see, it will be a lot easier to allocate the `Event[]` in C# and pass that to the unmanaged function.

Comment: I like your suggestion to allocate Event[] in C#. This was how wanted to do it to begin with, but I was unable to get it working. I am also unable to get it working properly this time. Could you help me out? I redefined the delegate as `private delegate Status GetEventList(ref Event[] eventList);`, and then allocated `Event[] eventList = new Event[2]`, followed by `getEventList(ref eventList);` (I removed the `Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem` and `Marshal.PtrToStructure` bits.) This gives a very nasty FatalExecutionEngineError. Any thoughts?

Comment: Can you update your question with your latest changes?

Comment: You should probably not use `ref` there. Try without it. The array will be marshalled as `Event*`

Comment: If I try without `ref` and write `private delegate Status GetEventList(Event*[] eventList)` I get the following error: "Cannot take the address of, get the size of, or declare a pointer to a managed type (Event)"

Comment: No! Dont make it a pointer. Just `delegate Status GetEventList(Event[] eventList)`

Comment: By the way you can always use PInvoke Interop Assistant (http://clrinterop.codeplex.com/releases/view/14120) anytime you are having problems with finding the right representation of unmanaged code in your managed applications.

Comment: leppie, if I do that then how would the eventList be populated? Because I have to call `getEventList(eventList)`, which of course won't do anything to eventList. Indeed, when I try it the code runs without any errors but eventList remains unpopulated. Am I missing something? Panos, thanks for the tip! This Assistant is new to me. I'll check it out.

Comment: Hey! I tried `delegate Status GetEventList([Out]Event[] eventList)`, and it worked!! I saw that notation on [link]http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164193.aspx which discusses the PInvoke Interop Assistant.

Comment: Glad it worked :) Now you can answer the question yourself!

Answer (score 0):

This is the code that finally did the trick:

```cs
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1, CharSet=CharSet.Ansi)]
public struct Event
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)]
    public int event_type;

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.R8)]
    public double time_stamp;

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 200)]
    public string event_text;
}

[UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
private delegate Status GetEventList([out]Event[] eventList);

public Event[] GetEventList()
{
    // this.pDll is a pointer to the dll library.
    IntPtr pAddressOfFunctionToCall = NativeMethods.GetProcAddress(this.pDll, "GetEventList");
    GetEventList getEventList = (GetEventList)Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer(pAddressOfFunctionToCall, typeof(GetEventList));

    Event[] eventList = new Event[2];
    getEventList(eventList);

    return eventList;
}
```

A big thank you to leppie and Panos Rontogiannis who helped me figure it out!